# Help with Demonstration of $C^3$ class solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's be $\Omega$ an open set, $f  \in C^{2}(\Omega ,R)$.

Demonstrate that each solution $\phi$ of the differential equation $y'=f(x,y)$ in $\Omega$ is  $C^{3}$ class in its definition domain

I don't even know how to start, I would appreciate some help.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi\colon I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a solution of the differential equation.

By definition, $\phi$ is a differentiable function such that
$$
\phi'(x) = f(x, \phi(x))
\qquad\forall x\in I.
$$
Consider the composite function $\Phi(x) := f(x, \phi(x))$.

Since $\phi$ and $f$ are continuous, this composition is continuous, hence the relation $\phi' = \Phi$ says that $\phi$ is of class $C^1$.

Since $\phi$ and $f$ are $C^1$, the composition $\Phi$ is $C^1$, hence the relation $\phi' = \Phi$ says that $\phi$ is of class $C^2$.

Since $\phi$ and $f$ are $C^2$, the composition $\Phi$ is $C^2$, hence the relation $\phi' = \Phi$ says that $\phi$ is of class $C^3$.

The same argument shows that, if $F\in C^k$, then $\phi\in C^{k+1}$.
In particular, if $F\in C^\infty$, then $\phi\in C^\infty$.